# Enabling Excel to Open Python CSV Output as UTF8

Tags: python, excel, csv, utf-8

I've worked through several similar posts around this issue, but to no avail - I output a list of lists to a `csv` file, however the special characters are not showing properly as Excel isn't reading it as `UTF8`.

I'm a beginner so am struggling to implement some of the workarounds people have used such as writing to  `UTF16` and using BOMs - my latest attempt was to try to add the BOM to my output `CSV` but its not working.

```
with open(outputname, "wb") as f:
  writer = csv.writer(f)
  writer.writerows(my_list)
  f.write(u'\ufeff'.encode('utf8')) # BOM
```

I've tried some more complicated ways like using UnicodeWriter, but with no luck. Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out, so just in case its useful for anyone else - I got around it by decoding my csv content (stored in a nested list prior to exporting to csv) and then re-encoding the content into 'cp1252' which I believe is the encoding used by Excel. Haven't tested this on Mac yet but it certainly works on Windows.

```
for i in range(len(nestedlist)):
    for j in range(7):
        x = nestedlist[i][j]
        y = unicode(x, 'utf-8')
        nestedlist[i][j] = y.encode('cp1252')
```

Comment: In hindsight, it would have been much easier to use openpyxl to handle the Excel element here.